# Ubuntu 14.04 along Windows 8 - Do you recommend?

Tags: dual-boot

I am having a problem with installing 13.04 on my Samsung, would you recommend to try installing 14.04 along Windows 8?

Comment: 13.04 is EOL, why would you want to install it? And why wouldn't you install 14.04?

Answer (score 1):

You should have no conflict between systems.
Remember that you'll need to use GRUB or LILO as bootloader, so install the Windows system first and after that let the Ubuntu installer overwrite the boot sector with GRUB.
Remember to **check the minimum requirements** for both systems before doing anything:

- [Official Windows® 8.1 & 8 requisites](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/system-requirements);
- [Official Ubuntu Desktop requisites](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).

NOTE: Windows 8 is obsolete, use Windows 8.1 if you can.
**In this community is forbidden to express personal opinions** on other systems or on trademarks; I can only give you objective observations:

- Install a Windows® system if you enjoy [Closed Source](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software) software: on those systems you can't be operative without it, because the system itself is not [Open Source](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source);
- The proprietary technology (like the one used by some eye candy games) used on Windows® may not be compatible with your Linux/Unix system but you should always find an [alternative free software](http://www.linuxalt.com/) on your Ubuntu Repository; if you are a professional gamer you need Windows for now;
- The concept of [User Friendly](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability) is very different in Linux and you may need to read the manuals or ask for help if in doubt. The community will be always here to help with any Linux problem; Ubuntu has the instructions to solve almost any problem already installed.

In general you'll not need a Windows® system or any other Closed Source system, because Linux Ubuntu is a complete system.

Follow the [Official Ubuntu installation guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) to know how to install your new Ubuntu system.
I suggest to use [torrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) to download the Ubuntu DVD/USB image, this protocols guarantees the file integrity and doesn't weight on the servers; click [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) to do so.
Please, feel free to *comment under here if you have more questions* and click the up arrow on the left if I'm of any help.